# the right element to bind an event

Tags: javascript, html

I have element `<a href="javascript: void(0)" id="bar">foo</a>`. `#bar` has a `click` event. I am telling freelancer that instead it would be better to use `<div />` (with style `cursor: pointer;` if needed) rather than hyperlink, since the actual `href=""` is not utilized anyway and there is no fallback (and can't be in this case) for JS-less version.

However, this comes from my rational-thinking & my experience. Thus, could anyone tell me whether I am right saying the latter and, if possible, provide a reference to a resource discussing this in more depth?

Answer (score 3):

That's a very good phillosophical question.

However, I'd recommend the use of a **button**. Rather then a clickable div.

The rationale behind this is that a `<div>` is meant to be a semanticless container, where a button is mean to "do something on the page", which much better describes what you are trying to achieve.

As a general rule, any `<a href="javascriot:void(0)">` or `<a href="#">` could probably be replaced with a `<button>`.

Answer (score 2):

You're right in saying that you should not use a link that doesn't link anywhere - that's definitely bad semantics.

But think about using something a bit more meaningful than `<div>` (a division/section of the page). Is it a button that you're clicking? Use `<button>`. Maybe it's more of a menu option? Use `<menu>` and `<command>` (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/interactive-elements.html#the-command-element). This is a good resource for finding the best element to match your needs:

http://joshduck.com/periodic-table.html

Comment: Hm. The problem with `<button>` element is that it has a lot of browser native CSS rules, such as background, border, doesn't listen to parent font-family/size/line-height, etc.